# Oracle Update on View extremly slow

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this simple UPDATE Statement:

```
  UPDATE   v_my_view mv
     SET   mv.name   = 
              (SELECT   RTRIM(name)
                 FROM   v_another_view av
                WHERE av.KEY_ID = mv.KEY_ID)
   WHERE mv.VALID = 1;
```

This Statement takes extremely long (20 secs), while other, more complicated updates on the same view take less than 1 second. First I thought it is the RTRIM function, but it's not, if I dont't use it, its slow as before.

SELECTs on both views return the records very fast.

There is no TRIGGER on the view, but there is one on the table behind. But it cannot be the bottleneck, since even when I comment all the TRIGGER code out, it has the same slow performance.

Anybody has a suggestion?

EDIT: Added missing WHERE clause
EDIT: The view (or the table behind) contains only 8000 records each, no special data types.

Comment: How are the views defined? ie., DDL of both v_my_view and v_another_view

Comment: What is the execution plan?

Comment: @toddlermenot: The views are very simple selects of only one table each behind.

Comment: @Wernfried: The execution plan I can not post here since its my company's code and tablenames. Anywhere, the COST is in every line pretty low (30-33) while in the sum on top it says 507214

Comment: What happens if you write the same update against the tables directly? Is it a 1 to 1 relationship on the `KEY_ID` fields? Do you see any cartesian/cross product operators in the query plan? Without a query plan we'll just need to take guesses and divide and conquer. Can you confirm that in the underlying tables, the total records (excluding any where clauses) are about 8000. i.e. 8000 is not the records expected to be affected, 8000 is the total number of actual records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the entire view without any WHERE clause.

If you have a big amount of data or even indexes, it could be slowing your operation.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the WHERE clause in my post, will do that now. Anyway, the complete number of records is appr. 8000...so pretty low I guess, and can't be the bottelneck.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any indexes on column `name` in underlying table of `v_my_view` ? If yes, disable them and see if it leads to any improvements on the performance of the query.
As Nick.McDermaid puts it, it is hard to say without execution plans and wait event statistics. The best you can hope for is some form of psychic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
merge --+ use_hash(MV,AV) no_merge(AV) no_merge(MV)
    into (select * from v_my_view MV where valid = 1)
using v_another_view AV
on MV.key_id = AV.key_id
when matched then
    update
    set MV.name = rtrim(AV.name)
;
```

Although I'm not absolutely sure about `merge`ing into an inline view, but you may try it at least (and post a comment if it does not work).

Also, it is a good practice to show execution plans of your queries along with the queries.